# Div being clickable

Tags: html

I have an image slideshow which i want all parts clickable:

```
<a href="/recruit.php">
<img src="img/Slide2.jpg" width="1000px" height="225px" alt="Slide 2"></a>
<div class="caption" style="bottom:0" >
    <p><a class="fill-div" href="/recruit.php">Apprenticeships – wide range available.</a></p>
</div>
```

According to google in HTML5 an `<a>` surrounding  `<div>` is valid HTML and should work however it doesn't. Both whats shown above and below do not work:

```
<a href="/recruit.php">
<img src="img/Slide2.jpg" width="1000px" height="225px" alt="Slide 2"></a><a href="/recruit.php">
<div class="caption" style="bottom:0" >
    <p>Apprenticeships – wide range available.</p>
</div></a>
```

How am i able to make either the text or the whole box clickable and go to the link?

Comment: "There is a lot of relevant CSS that might be breaking it" — Yes. Make a [test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that the relevent code is in the question ([Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).). Creating the reduced test case might lead you into finding the cause of the bug yourself.

Comment: A working example is not a link to your website. Try to reproduce the problem in a stacksnippet or in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry ill try and sort out an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="/recruit.php" style="display:block; background-color:#ccc;">
  <img src="img/Slide2.jpg" width="1000px" height="225px" alt="Slide 2">
  <div class="caption" style="bottom:0" >
    <p>Apprenticeships – wide range available.</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

This works in my Chrome as you described. Notice `display:block` (or inline-block) style that you need to add to `<a>`.

Comment: @Bozidar: Could you please tell how did you know that adding `display-block` would make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Simple answer: experience. 
But to be more specific, I had same problem sometimes in past and I've figured it out by learning DOM more thoroughly. Some elements behave like blocking elements (like <div>), some don't (like <span>) and in general, if you want <span> to behave like <div>, you define display property as "block". In my opinion, the most important thing to learn, if one wants to do any coding that has to do with web, is to learn DOM, what it means, how it works, how is implemented/interpreted.... After that, it's easy to learn JS (and than any JS framework/library) or html, css...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointer-events` for any situation:

- Make an element that's normally not clickable, clickable (e.g. a div that behaves like a real button element)
- Make an element that's normally clickable, not clickable (e.g. an anchor that can't be clicked as if it was disabled)
- Nested clickable elements within a non-clickable element (or even within multiple layers) can still be accessed (even if behind an overlay)

[**`pointer-events`**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

[**`CanIUse`**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

**Snippet**

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.clk {
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
}
.clk:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  color: gold;
}
.not {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
.not:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  color: #ddd;
}
#pointB {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -300px;
  left: 50%;
}
#pointA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<a href="#pointB" class="clk" style="position: absolute">
  <div id="pointA" class="clk">pointA</div>
  <a>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <p class="not">This demo shows how the CSS property, <code class="clk">pointer-events</code> can be used.</p>
    <dl class="not">
      <dt class="clk">Usage</dt>
      <dd class="not">Each element will either have the .clk or .not class.</dd>
      <dd class="not">An element with a red border belongs to the .not class.</dd>
      <dd class="clk">An element with a blue border belongs to the .clk class.</dd>
      <dt class="not">CSS</dt>
      <dd class="clk"><code class="not">.clk { pointer-events: auto; cursor: pointer; border: 1px dashed blue; background: rgba(0,0,255,.3); }</code>
      </dd>
      <dd class="not"><code class="clk">.not { pointer-events: none; border: 1px dashed red; background: rgba(255,0,0,.3); }</code>
      </dd>
    </dl>

    <section class="not">
      <div class="clk"></div>
      <span class="not">
    <a href="#pointA" class="clk">Click Here</a>
    </span>
    </section>
    <label class="not">Check This Box</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="not">
    <label class="clk">Check This Box</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="clk">
    <a href="#pointA" class="not">Click Here</a>
    <a href="#pointA" class="clk">Click Here</a>



    <a href="#pointA"><b id="pointB" class="clk">pointB</b></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Making all clickable</title>
  <style>
    #page{
    width: 100%;
 background: white;
 overflow: hidden;/*height: 1%;*/
 position:relative;
    }
    #page a{
      display:block;
      z-index:2;
      position:relative;
    }
   #page a.white-space-link{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 z-index:1; 
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page">
<a href="#">  <img src="img/Slide2.jpg" width="1000px" height="225px" alt="Slide 2"></a>
    <a class="white-space-link" href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"> <p>Apprenticeships – wide range available.</p> </a>   
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check, if this is what you wanted. Making all a link, whether it's a image or text, all becomes a link together

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is your css. Infact, your `<a>` may not contains all the elements inside: if you make `overflow:hidden`, you will see the parts covered by `<a>`.

So I suggest you to use the inspector of your browser and play with css rules so the `<a>` cover all block. A `display:inline-block` for `<a>` can be a possibility.

Comment: You seem to be making vague guesses and suggesting possible debugging techniques instead of actually identifying the problem. This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: That's true I have made more a guess than a precise answer. But I have already faced the same problem and the solution was to analyse css. It would be for me a pleasure to comment before answering, but I don't have the right yet and I wanna help.

Comment: "solution was to analyse css" — That's not the solution, that's a method you use to find the solution.

Comment: "I don't have the right yet and I wanna help" — Help on other questions where you can contribute something more than a comment until you have earned the right to make comments.